# How to sign a .NET Assembly DLL file with a Strong Name?

Tags: .net, code-signing

I have an assembly which is not strong-named. I have no source code for it.

I now need it to be signed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22):

If the original assembly is marked for delayed signing, then you can use the sn.exe tool.

If the original assembly is not so marked, then you can disassemble it with ildasm.exe, then re-asssemble it with ilasm.exe and specify the /key argument. References: [[1]](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/) [[2]](https://edanan.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/how-to-sign-assembly-with-strong-name/).

Example:

```
> ildasm /all /out=MYASSEMBLY.il MYASSEMBLY.dll
> ilasm /dll /key=key.snk MYASSEMBLY.il
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(VS.71).aspx   
MSDN said using:al /out:MyAssembly.dll MyModule.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk     . But I did not succeed

Comment: What about keeping the pdb file in sync?

Comment: If the assembly references another DLL that you are also strongly signing, you get errors stating that it cannot find the unsigned version.  Is there a way to update the referenced DLL signatures in the file?

Answer (score 11):

Easy way to sign 3rd party assembly is using the **`GUI`** version of **`Assembly Strong Name Signer`**, available here: http://brutaldev.com/post/2013/10/18/NET-Assembly-Strong-Name-Signer.

It's source code is available on Github. Uses `Mono.Cecil` for the dirty work. Available also as `command line` tool.

I have found the recommended `ildasm` -> `ilasm` round trip suggested at several places cumbersome and better to be avoided.

I don't know how `Assembly Strong Name Signer` handles multi-assembly dependencies. In case it does not , the problem and it's solution is described here (published 2008): http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/

Comment: very easy to use, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my [StrongNameResigner](https://github.com/martinkirsche/StrongNameResigner). It can sign or resign an assembly and all assemblies that depend on it while also updating all references using a command like that:

```
StrongNameResigner.exe -a "c:\temp" -k "key.snk" Foo.Bar
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I get an exception:

Unable find dependend assemblies: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'myassembly.dll, Culture=....

Answer (score 2):

Use the Strong Name Tool utility ([sn.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx)).

Comment: sn.exe can't do this,becacuse sn.exe just can re-sign with storng name assembly

Comment: I think sn.exe works if the original assembly is marked to be signed later.  yes?

Comment: to Cheeso: Yes,you are right,i found a way:http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx

Comment: This answer is correct when you use "delayed signing" using the public key of the snk-file and then re-sign it using `sn -R MyDLL.dll MySNKFileWithPrivateKey.snk`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/delay-sign for more information.

Answer (score -4):

```
You can sign the assembly with the help of VS command prompt.
Just type the path in VS cmd prompt where your project is physically present.

In VS cmd
<your project path>sn -k <name of your project>.snk

Then go to your project in Solution Explorer -> properties -> Signing -> check checkbox  
-> Browse to the key which is created using VS cmd.
```

Comment: OP: _" I have no source code for it."_