# Is it possible to resign a signed .net dll with a different key pair?

Tags: c#, .net, security, assemblies

My colleague deploy a dll and he signed with the key generated on his machine.Right now I need to use the DLL in my project, so I need to resign the DLL, I generate a key pair on my computer, then try to resign it with sn.exe -R or sn.exe -Vr , but always failed.

Is it possible to resign a signed .net dll with a different key pair?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [How to sign a .NET Assembly DLL file with a Strong Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220519/how-to-sign-a-net-assembly-dll-file-with-a-strong-name)

[Ryan Farley's linked article](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx) suggests:

> disassemble the DLL to IL and then
>   reassemble the IL back into a DLL and
>   include the new key file.