# C# Build a strong named file with imported non strong name libraries

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, gac, strongname

I have a problem when building my strong name file solution. I need it to have a strong name since i need to deploy it to the GAC. The problem is that one of my imported libraries doesn't have a strong name. When I build the solution I get this error code:

> Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'MathNet.Numerics' does not have a strong name  c:\visual studio 2013\Projects\Math\Math\CSC    Math

So my question is. Is it possible to build a strong name dll when the solution contains imported non strong name dll:s? If so, how would one go about building a solution of this kind?

PS.
I references the keyfile in the AssemblyInfo.cs file the following way

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("C:\\MyStrongKeys.snk")]
```

Comment: This site describes it good to. [How to sign third party assemblies](http://erjjones.github.io/blog/How-to-sign-third-party-assemblies/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't reference an unsigned assembly from a strong nammed assembly.

> strong-named assemblies can only reference other strong-named assemblies.

See why on [MSDN : Strong-Nammed Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wd40t7ad.aspx) (last paragraph).

You'll have to [sign the referenced assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220519/how-to-sign-a-net-assembly-dll-file-with-a-strong-name).