# Why Machine.Specifications recommends to use unsigned binaries?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mspec, machine.fakes

On [**Machine.Specifications**](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) github page I can download both signed and unsigned binaries, and unsigned binaries are recommended.

In my .net project all assemblies should be signed by a key. This is external requirement.

Also I use InternalsVisibleTo attribute to provide access for unit test assembly to internal memebers of all other assemblies.
If you use InternalsVisibleTo attribute on signed assembly, assembly that will access internals also should be signed.

So my unit test assembly should be signed.
This means that I can't use unsigned versions of any unit test frameworks.

I have found signed versions of Machine.Specifications on Nuget, but I want also to use **Machine.Fakes** as automocking container and can't find signed version of Machine.Fakes.

So I can't use Machine.Fakes in my project.

I just can't understand, how can I follow "recomended way" in my case?
Probably I should add conditional compilation of main assemblies - unsigned versions for unit testing and signed versions for releasing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977363/using-unsigned-assemblies-in-signed-ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options:

- As you mentioned, create an unsigned version of your assembly to run the tests on.
- As mentioned by nikita, sign the Machine.Fakes assembly manually as described in
  [using unsigned assemblies in signed ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977363/using-unsigned-assemblies-in-signed-ones).
- Or you pull the sources of [Machine.Fakes](https://github.com/machine/machine.fakes) and compile and sign the assembly yourself.

There is no signed version of Machine.Fakes, because nobody needed it so far. I have seen the [issue you filed](https://github.com/machine/machine.fakes/issues/19), but I haven't had time to have a look at it yet. So there is another option: wait for me to create a signed version. :-) However, I am not sure yet if and how I would do that.

Comment: Understand you well.
I suppose to create set of unsigned assemblies just for unit testing.
This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the signed version, you also need the signed ReSharper runner. And both versions need to match.

With the unsigned versions, it's possible to use another version in ReSharper and your project, provided the internal APIs are compatible.

From my point of view, the former is more hassle (keeping both versions in sync), hence the recommendation. It's also what I use to test and for my own work.