# Giving a custom .dll API a strong name

Tags: c#, api, dll

I've been looking around, and can't find a direct answer for this anywhere. Pretty much, I have a program that runs fine in debug and I'm ready to publish it. I have one problem though. My friend gave me a custom API (.dll) to use, and now I get the following error when trying to publish:

> Error 1    Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly
>   'CustomAPI' does not have a strong name

In short, how do I give it a "strong name"?

Comment: Please take a look at the following question complaining about the same problem you are facing: [c# - How to fix "Referenced assembly does not have a strong name" error (VS2005) - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error-vs2005). Have a great day :)

Comment: How about going to property panel of the project, then to signing tab and add a signature to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the assembly's source then see [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Otherwise, read this [blog post](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/).