# Installing NHunspell in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, spell-checking, hunspell, nhunspell

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on installing NHunspell in VS 2010.  Maybe it's just me but there seems to be very little about the installation of this spell checker.  I've downloaded different projects, with different sizes, and this C# newbie is needing a little help getting this installed.  Some of these articles talk about needing a reference, some talk about adding libraries/projects to your project, etc.  And one other thing, is it NHunspell or Hunspell?

One download I have, has the following files:  Hunspellx64.dll, Hunspellx86.dll, NHunspell.dll, NHunspell.pdb, NHunspell.xml.

Another has folders like:  _UpgradeReport_Files, ~Used, Components, i00SpellCheck, Plugins, Tests, Web.

In my Solution Explorer, I see a reference called:  NHunspellExtender

People talk about 'Extension Manager' and NuGet Package Manager, etc.

I really think making this tool work in my code won't be difficult IF I can get it installed and setup properly!  Please bear with this newbie.  I've even had it come back with a "Referenced Assembly does not have a Strong Name" error.  Help!

Thanks, 
Craig

Comment: There's nothing to install - it's a 3rd party library like any other. Add a reference to the DLLs if you don't want to use NuGet. If you're getting a strong named error, it's because you're trying to reference an unsigned assembly from your signed project. In this case you have a couple of options: build the library from source and sign yourself, load the assembly dynamically, or don't sign your assembly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error and the page the accepted answer links to.

Comment: OK, I tried installing this again and things are working now.  I've got a couple more questions, but I'll post them in a new question if I can't find someone already asking the same stuff!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the NHunspell NuGet package. It has scripts for copying the native DLLs in the output directories.