# Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis' does not have a strong name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, snk

Not sure if many of you have tried this but I've created a component using Google's .net and referenced one of their .dlls. I am using a classic .asp as my interface to upload a document to the Google Drive and in order for the classic .asp to talk to a .Net 4.0 component, a strong name has to be generated in which I did for the main component, but for some reason it keep giving me the error

"Error 1 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis' does not have a strong name"

So I created a .snk for Google.Apis and still getting the same error, not sure what else to do

please help

Thanks

MAC

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error

Comment: thanks for the quick response Matt, but most of the answers on the link you've provided was to disable the "sign the assembly". I am using Visual Studio 2010 and in order for my asp-classic interface to talk to this .Net 4.0 component is to have the snk

Answer (score 0):

You will need create various strong names per dll and assign the strong name and sign in your .dll file.

Comment: I did that too...
I've created strong name for the main component as well as for Google.Apis and yet, every time I would re-build the component, I get the same error

Comment: Mmmm, see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: yeah, that's what I've used to create strong name for this third party dll and yet my visual studio 2010 keeps complaining about "Assembly generation failed — Referenced assembly 'Google.Apis' does not have a strong name".. not sure what am I missing

Comment: although, under the Google.Apis.dll properties, the section for Strong name is grayed out and has a value of "False".

Comment: its a package that can be downloaded from google in order for me to integrate my app to their Google Drive

Comment: Mmmm It is strange, you should be able to sign the google api, one question, your projects have a Strong Names? All projects needed a Strong name and sign.

Comment: yes, my project alone does have a strong name and since I referenced the Google.Apis.dll, for some reason visual studio is asking for their string name as well... so I've created Google.Apis.snk and still complaining with the same error

Comment: Try add strong names in all projects.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm wanting to pull data from Google Drive Sheets into my Classic ASP application.