# Build Error after third party assembly was strongly named.

Tags: c#, dll, mongodb-.net-driver, gac

I have been working on upgrading my application to use the MongoDB 2.0 driver, but have hit a road block since MongoDB is not currently releasing a strongly named version of the assemblies. As a result I cannot build an assembly in my solution that gets registered in the Global Assembly cache (GAC) because GAC requires assemblies to be strongly named.

Using the technique explained on [Ian Picknell's](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-strong-name-to-third-party.html) and [Ryan Farley's](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2010/04/23/sign-a-.net-assembly-with-a-strong-name-without-recompiling.aspx) Blogs I was able to strongly name the assemblies; `MongoDB.Bson.dll,` `MongoDB.Driver.dll`, and `MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll`. After strongly signing them I removed the old references to these assemblies and added references to the new strongly named versions. When I try to build the project in VS2013 2 errors(see below) are generated both of which are trying to reference the weakly named assembly (This is my understanding because the error states PublicKeyToken=null).

I've also tried building strongly named assemblies straight from the source code since MongoDB is open source but that has been generating hundreds of errors that i'm still working through.

```
Error   1   The type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.0.1.27, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Error   2   The type 'MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSource`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MongoDB.Driver.Core, Version=2.0.1.27, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read topic [331520](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error) and Dirk Vollmar's answer (Also give him an upvote). The link he provides explained the problem I was encountering.

A quick summary of the problem was the original MongoDB.Driver.dll and MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll were built with a reference to the unsigned version of MongoDB.Bson, so I had to update the references inside of those DLL's to include the publickeytoken I used to sign the assemblies. All is explained by the .NET-fu article under the Foo, Bar, Baz section.

Answer (score 3):

I Installed the nuget package [StrongNamer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StrongNamer/) and it signed automatically the unsigned dependencies.

> Strong Namer will automatically add strong names to referenced
>   assemblies which do not already have a strong name. This will allow
>   you to reference and use NuGet packages with assemblies which are not
>   strong named from your projects that do use a strong name.

Comment: I'll have to check this out.

Comment: Doeasn't work. Still get error about unsigned dll's