# Referenced assembly does not have a strong name c#

Tags: c#, .net

I thought this would be dead simple to create a class library as Mydomain.Common

Then use this class library in my other projects libraries

MyDomain.OtherA

MyDomain.OtherB

I wan to use Mydomain.Common class library in both projects.

But I also want to use Mydomain.OtherA in Mydomain.OtherB project.

When I add the references and try to build the solution I get the error saying "eferenced assembly does not have a strong name".

I did read on answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error) but I couldn't make sense of it.

How can I achieve this?

I know that in many projects we use this approach to install nuget package in multiple projects and those projects also references another common project.

For example EF, Autofac, AutoMapper.

Is this not possible? Do I really need to sign the dll to use it in this scenario?

Comment: you only *need* to strong-name a library if you are trying to use it from another strong-named project. Are you sure one of your otherA/B projects doesn't have strong naming turned on?

Comment: is there any way to check it? what is exactly strong name? is there any advantage of it? and how to turn it off? thanks

Comment: Right click your project, select "Properties", go to the "Signing" tab and make sure that "Sign the assembly" is not checked. Signed assemblies are useful when you want to make sure that somebody isn't going to change it and redistribute it as the publisher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Referenced assembly does not have a strong name" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error)