# DocuSign: Signed Library v3.0.0

Tags: docusignapi

I am evaluating DocuSign for our demo product. I have created a demo using your RestApi libraries in ASP.Net MVC Project and is working fine.

I used the same code in our project but the code crashes with “Could not load assembly or reference” error. After a lot of R&D I found that the issue is because the library provided by DocuSign v3.0.0 is not signed.

As an alternate I started using v2.0.0 which is a signed library provided by DocuSign. The issue is resolved now but now I am getting an exception when trying to add Configuration header in Envelope “An item with the same key has already been added”. I have attached code sample for your reference.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        AccountID = DocLogin();
        EnvelopeID = CreateSendEnvelope(AccountID);

        // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnvelopeID))
            // EmbeddedSigning(AccountID, EnvelopeID);
    }

    private string DocLogin()
    {
        string accountId = null;
        try
        {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            Configuration cfi = new Configuration(apiClient);
            // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
            cfi.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            // we will retrieve this from the login API call
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(cfi);
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
            accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string inner = ex.Message;
        }

        return accountId;
    }

    private string CreateSendEnvelope(string accountID)
    {
        string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Document.docx");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountID))
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdfPath))
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
                EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
                envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";

                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                doc.Name = "Document.docx";
                doc.DocumentId = "1";
                doc.FileExtension = "docx";

                envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
                envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

                Signer signer = new Signer();
                signer.Email = userEmail;
                signer.Name = userDisplayName;
                signer.RecipientId = "1";
                signer.ClientUserId = "1001";
                signer.Tabs = new Tabs();

                signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
                SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
                signHere.DocumentId = "1";
                signHere.PageNumber = "1";
                signHere.RecipientId = "1";
                signHere.XPosition = "90";
                signHere.YPosition = "452";

                signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
                envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
                envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
                envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

                // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request 
                envDef.Status = "sent";

                // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests) 
                EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

                string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
                envelopesApi.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

                EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envDef);
                return envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about v3.0.0 but I have just checked the Nuget DocuSign package v3.0.1 and it is signed. See output below:

```
nuget install DocuSign.eSign.dll
(v3.0.1 installed)

cd .\DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1

nuget verify -Signatures .\DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1.nupkg

Verifying DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1
C:\Users\larry.kluger\DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1\.\DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1.nupkg

Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Signature type: Repository
nuget-v3-service-index-url: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
nuget-package-owners: DocuSign
Verifying the repository primary signature with certificate:
  Subject Name: CN=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, O=NuGet.org Repository by Microsoft, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  SHA1 hash: 8FB6D7FCF7AD49EB774446EFE778B33365BB7BFB
  SHA256 hash: 0E5F38F57DC1BCC806D8494F4F90FBCEDD988B46760709CBEEC6F4219AA6157D
  Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Valid from: 4/10/2018 3:00:00 AM to 4/14/2021 3:00:00 PM

Timestamp: 8/17/2018 2:30:20 AM

Verifying repository primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate:
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G2, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: 625AEC3AE4EDA1D169C4EE909E85B3BBC61076D3
  SHA256 hash: CF7AC17AD047ECD5FDC36822031B12D4EF078B6F2B4C5E6BA41F8FF2CF4BAD67
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 1/2/2017 2:00:00 AM to 4/2/2028 2:59:59 AM


Successfully verified package 'DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1'.
```

### Added

The OP has commented that he is asking about the SDK being [**Strong Named.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies)

1. I have submitted DocuSign internal enhancement request DCM-2784.
   Please contact your DocuSign Customer Service contact to have
   your name and company information added to the ticket.
2. There appears to be work-arounds for this issue. See [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331520/how-to-fix-referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name-error)
3. Pedro Lamas feels that developers shouldn't Strong Name libraries
   [anymore.](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2016/03/01/still-strong-naming-your-assemblies-you-do-know-its-2016-right/)

Comment: I dont find it Strong Named.

    <Reference Include="DocuSign.eSign, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DocuSign.eSign.dll.3.0.1\lib\net45\DocuSign.eSign.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>